# Big Query - Concurrency for dashboard design

Tags: google-bigquery, dashboard

Is big query suitable to handle hundred of thousands of connections or this is a bad design?

Situation, currently building a dashboard that will display aggregated values pulled straight from big query. In our dashboard, we also have a set of date filters that can display up to previous year worth of data(each filter will be a unique query to big query). It's highly possible that hundreds of thousands of users will access the dashboard at the same time.

Read from the documentation that big query has a set quota on the number of queries that can be run at the same time. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

If this is really a problem, the solution I'm planning is to precalculate every unique date results and persist it in fast table but we are talking a lot of combinations in here. Is this the right architecture to go or big query has another trick in the bag to address this concern?

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few things to note here.

1. The 100 concurrent queries can be raised.
2. If you raise the limit you need to make sure you have the supporting slots underneath to handle the requests. The on-demand pricing gives you 2,000 slots, given the workload you are talking about you may need additional slots to handle the concurrency which means flat rate pricing.
3. You may be able to mitigate some of this by relying on the result cache, or if your data updates regularly a materialized view.